# Extract order item field data

Tags: commerce

On a Drupal 9/Commerce 2 installation, I have a Gift Card product through the commerce_giftcard module. When a customer places a Gift Card order, I need to automatically send an email with the Gift Card code. I wrote a custom module to do that, but the problem is: how do I get the Gift Card code starting from the order? I managed to dig it out with a raw SQL query like so:

```
SELECT code
FROM commerce_giftcard g
JOIN commerce_giftcard_transaction t ON t.giftcard = g.id
JOIN commerce_order_item i ON t.reference_id = i.order_item_id
JOIN commerce_order o ON o.order_id = i.order_id
WHERE o.order_id = $id
```

This works but it's horrible, and when I need to add a custom field (like a message from the donor), it becomes even messier.

How can we drill down to the Gift Card data (or any other order item data) in a more Drupal-like way?

Comment: I'm not a commerce user, so I can't help with the answer, but I can tell you that a DB query is almost definitely not the way to go, as it will cause caching issues, and bypasses a lot of APIs that are there to improve performance. Likely you need to load some entity and get the value from that.

Comment: There is definitely an API for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided that in this case an SQL query is probably the most efficient way after all. Drupal does have a [Database API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api)
just for that, and I used the [Static Queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries) method.

There is no possible caching involved because this is data to be used only once to send an email inside an event subscriber, so a single hit to the database seems to be the most straightforward and economical solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).